# WordPress shortcode function gives white page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a shortcode for my own WordPress theme. I created this:

```
function link($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "to" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com'
    ), $atts));
    return '<a href="'.$to.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}

add_shortcode("link", "link");
```

But when I add this to my functions.php between opening and closing PHP-tags, it gives me a white page when I enter whatever WordPress page. So wp-admin and normal pages are all white.

I added it on top of functions.php and at the bottom. Neither worked. Can somebody explain why I get this?

Comment: Make sure you don't have extra space in the end of `functions.php` file

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code...

```
function mylink($atts, $content = null) { 
     extract(shortcode_atts(array("to" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com' ), $atts));
     return '<a href="'.$to.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}

add_shortcode("mylink", "mylink");
```

link is default keyword so you can not use link.

i hope you will get.

Comment: I got this now:

    function infobutton($atts, $content = null) { 
     extract(shortcode_atts(array("tekst" => 'Meer informatie' ), $atts));
     return '<div class="container extend">
    <h2 class="center">'.echo $content.' <a href="pakket" class="button-orange-small">'.echo $tekst.'</a></h2>
   </div>';
}

add_shortcode("infobutton", "infobutton");

But it still gives a white page

Comment: @Chiel please edit your question and update your codes in question.

Comment: Yes @jogesh_pi is right.

please remove echo statement while you are returning some data.

i mean remove echo statement before $content and $tekst

Answer (score 0):

Accrording to your codes in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864459/wordpress-shortcode-function-gives-white-page?nah=29864768#comment-47854447):

```
function infobutton($atts, $content = null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array("tekst" => 'Meer informatie' ), $atts)); 
    return '<div class="container extend"> <h2 class="center">'.echo $content.' <a href="pakket" class="button-orange-small">'.echo $tekst.'</a></h2> </div>'; 
} 
add_shortcode("infobutton", "infobutton");
```

You don't need to use echo while you returning the value, it should be like this:

```
function infobutton($atts, $content = null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array("tekst" => 'Meer informatie' ), $atts)); 
    return '<div class="container extend"> <h2 class="center">'.$content.' <a href="pakket" class="button-orange-small">'.$tekst.'</a></h2> </div>'; 
} 
add_shortcode("infobutton", "infobutton");
```